# Iterate through web pages and download PDFs

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I have a code for crawling through all PDF files on web page and download them to folder. However now it started to drop an error:

> System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.   Source=NW Crawler
>   StackTrace:    at NW_Crawler.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\PC\source\repos\NW Crawler\NW Crawler\Program.cs:line 16

Pointing to `ProductListPage` in `foreach (HtmlNode src in ProductListPage)`

Is there any hint on how to fix this issue? I have tried to implement async/await with no success. Maybe I was doing something wrong tho...

Here is the process to be done:

1. Go to `https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/`
2. List all links in section (related products). They are: `<a class="ap-area-link" href="https://www.nordicwater.com/product/mrs-meva-multi-rake-screen/">MRS MEVA multi rake screen</a>`
3. Proceed to each link and search for PDF files. PDF files are in:

   ```
                   <div class="dl-items">
   <a href="https://www.nordicwater.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/S1126-MRS-brochure-EN.pdf" download="">
   ```

Here is my full code for testing:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Net;


namespace NW_Crawler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            {
                HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/");
                HtmlNodeCollection ProductListPage = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='ap-area-link']//a");
                Console.WriteLine("Here are the links:" + ProductListPage);
                foreach (HtmlNode src in ProductListPage)
                {
                    htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(src.Attributes["href"].Value);

                    // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                    HtmlNodeCollection LinkTester = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dl-items']//a");
                    if (LinkTester != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var dllink in LinkTester)
                        {
                            string LinkURL = dllink.Attributes["href"].Value;
                            Console.WriteLine(LinkURL);

                            string ExtractFilename = LinkURL.Substring(LinkURL.LastIndexOf("/"));
                            var DLClient = new WebClient();

                            // Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait some time

                            DLClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(LinkURL), @"C:\temp\" + ExtractFilename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if ProductListPage is not null?

Comment: You mean by adding `Console.WriteLine("Here are the links:" + ProductListPage);`? Yes seems like null, but why?

Comment: Try this xpath: `//a[@class='ap-area-link']` you don't have another nested anchor inside that in the link that you've shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a couple of changes to cover the errors you might be seeing.

**Changes**

1. Use of `src.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty)` instead of `src.Attribute["href"].Value;`. If the href is not present or null, you will get Object Reference Not Set to an instance of an object
2. Check if `ProductListPage` is valid and not null.
3. `ExtractFileName` includes a / in the name. You want to use + 1 in the substring method to skip that 'Last / from index of)'.
4. Move on to the next iteration if the href is null on either of the loops
5. Changed the Product List query to `//a[@class='ap-area-link']` from `//a[@class='ap-area-link']//a`. You were searching for `<a>` within the `<a>` tag which is null. Still, if you want to query it this way, the first IF statement to check if `ProductListPage != null` will take care of errors.

```
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/");
    HtmlNodeCollection ProductListPage = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='ap-area-link']");
    if (ProductListPage != null)
        foreach (HtmlNode src in ProductListPage)
        {
            string href = src.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(href))
                continue;
            htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(href);
            HtmlNodeCollection LinkTester = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dl-items']//a");
            if (LinkTester != null)
                foreach (var dllink in LinkTester)
                {
                    string LinkURL = dllink.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkURL))
                        continue;
                    string ExtractFilename = LinkURL.Substring(LinkURL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    new WebClient().DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(LinkURL), @"C:\temp\" + ExtractFilename);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your answer. I accidentally deleted my question - comment. Why there might be a problem with VPN?

Comment: If your VPN network does not allow access to the website, you would get a null for ProductListPage variable based on your SelectNodes query.

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath that you used seems to be incorrect. I tried loading the web page in a browser and did a search for the xpath and got no results. I replaced it with `//a[@class='ap-area-link']` and was able to find matching elements, screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Ok, then there is something with Interent connection. I have been testing this code on different web sites. When I had fast interent connection it was working on another site with correct XPaths. However now I am on mobile network and it is dropping errors all the time. Is there something with speed or something else? Should some code for waiting be added or where might be the problem with poor internet connection?

Comment: Ensure the page is loaded, if you're getting unexpected errors 'try and catch' them.

Comment: Is there any tip how to do that?